# Set SQL Server Permissions for Debugging

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to start debug stored procedure unfortunately all the time I get error. Do you know how to fix it?

[image]

I gave sysadmin to user and also I do this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1bhybwz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but doesn`t work.

Answer (score 0):

There was problem with domain now I can debug procedure.